# Javascript Recursion: Breaking out

Tags: javascript, recursion, google-chrome-extension

I'm having difficulty breaking out of this recursive function. The script is a background script for a chrome extension and is sending commands to a content script on the page. For each element in jsonArray, the script will need to:

1. Query the page and wait for page refresh
2. Grab specific headers

Once it has completed the whole array, it should stop.

Here's what I got:

```
function goGetEm(counter, path){

    key = jsonArray[counter];

    console.log("This is round "+counter+" and I am going to "+path);

    if(counter>=jsonArray.length){
        console.log("finishing");
        return;
    }

    if(path=="query"){
        console.log("querying "+jsonArray[counter]);
        message.sendMessage(tabID, {
            "submitquery": {
                "query": jsonArray[counter],
                "searchFieldID": searchFieldID,
                "submitID": submitID
            }
        }, function(response){
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabID , info) {
                if (info.status == "complete") {
                    console.log("query complete");
                    goGetEm(counter, "grab");
                    return;
                }
            });
        });
    }
    else if(path=="grab"){
        console.log("grabbing");
        message.sendMessage(tabID, {
            "grabdata": {
                "targetID": targetID
            }
        }, function(response){
            console.log("grab complete");
            saveData(key, response);
            goGetEm(counter+1, "query");
            return;
        });
    }
    return;
}

goGetEm(0, "query");
```

The function does successfully submit queries and grab data. But I believe I'm losing track of all the different loops that are being called and not ending them correctly (I thought that's what all my "returns" would do)..

Here is the output (well, some of it)

```
This is round 0 and I am going to query bg.js:58
querying element0 bg.js:66
query complete bg.js:76
This is round 0 and I am going to grab bg.js:58
grabbing bg.js:84
grab complete bg.js:90
This is round 1 and I am going to query bg.js:58
querying element1 bg.js:66
query complete bg.js:76
This is round 0 and I am going to grab bg.js:58
grabbing bg.js:84
query complete bg.js:76
This is round 1 and I am going to grab bg.js:58
grabbing bg.js:84
grab complete bg.js:90
This is round 1 and I am going to query bg.js:58
querying element1 bg.js:66
grab complete bg.js:90
This is round 2 and I am going to query bg.js:58
finishing bg.js:60
Object
 bg.js:48
query complete bg.js:76
This is round 0 and I am going to grab bg.js:58
grabbing bg.js:84
query complete bg.js:76
This is round 1 and I am going to grab bg.js:58
grabbing bg.js:84
query complete bg.js:76
This is round 1 and I am going to grab bg.js:58
grabbing bg.js:84
grab complete bg.js:90
This is round 1 and I am going to query bg.js:58
querying element1 bg.js:66
grab complete bg.js:90
This is round 2 and I am going to query bg.js:58
finishing bg.js:60
Object
 bg.js:48
grab complete bg.js:90
This is round 2 and I am going to query bg.js:58
finishing bg.js:60
Object
 bg.js:48
query complete bg.js:76
This is round 0 and I am going to grab bg.js:58
grabbing bg.js:84
query complete bg.js:76
This is round 1 and I am going to grab bg.js:58
grabbing bg.js:84
query complete bg.js:76
This is round 1 and I am going to grab bg.js:58
grabbing bg.js:84
query complete bg.js:76
This is round 1 and I am going to grab bg.js:58
grabbing bg.js:84
grab complete bg.js:90
This is round 1 and I am going to query bg.js:58
querying element1 bg.js:66
grab complete bg.js:90
```

and on....

Comment: I'm a bit confused on two accounts. First, in the "query" part, do you even need to wait for a response? You're not using it for anything. Second, it seems like you're registering a ton of listeners to the same tab which will all fire repeatedly.

Comment: @Xan, the query will ask the content script to submit a form. The background script will need to wait for the tab to reload (and then grab headers from the results). Does this need to happen as the callback? Probably not. I thought it would be a convenient place to hold the function form part two, the grab.

Comment: @Xan, you make a good point about adding all the listeners. I guess I thought the listener would disappear after the refresh. I needed the listener since I needed the function to wait for the target tab to submit and reload.

Comment: As I see it, the listener is attached to the tab and not the page

Comment: Indeed, then I'll probably need to take a different approach -- perhaps something similar to what @David Erhmann answered below. Although I'm unsure exactly how to implement what he suggested. Xan, might you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think what's mixing you up is you have async IO going on in there. Recursion is about calling the current function and maintaining a call stack, but because you're dealing with callbacks, that doesn't really happen like you think. This `return` returns from the listener, not the outer container.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabID , info) {
    if (info.status == "complete") {
        console.log("query complete");
        goGetEm(counter, "grab");
        return;
    }
});
```

What I'd do is rewrite it so it's iterative. I'd have an object with the callback methods, and the object internally tracks state in the same way you would with a stack.

```
var worker = {
    queue:[],
    onUpdatedListener: function(tabID , info) {
        ...
    },
    sendMessageComplete: function(response) { ... },
    doWork: function(...) { ... },
    init: function(queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }
}

worker.init(jsonArray);
worker.doWork();
```

Comment: I'm a bit unsure how this would work. So my "submitquery" and "grabdata" messages would both be stuffed into doWork(). How should this object be iterated? How does it wait for message responses to continue? Perhaps you can fill in a bit more to your example?

Comment: The callbacks all trigger the next "iteration."